# mySQL in server Terminal, need to see output

Tags: php, mysql, linux, terminal

I am a little bit stuck having to execute a mySQL query in the terminal of one of my servers.

Here is how far I got:

```
mysql -u myUsername -p myPassword myDatabaseName -e "SHOW PROCESSLIST;"
```

So basically something is eating my server and I wanted to see what was going on in my SQL when I refresh pages. I'm really on the new side of terminal commands, so I'm not sure if its structured right, but **I will need to have the results echoed out as well.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable logging for your mysql server with the following command:

```
mysql -u myUsername -p myPassword -e "SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;"
```

Then you should use tail command for the log:

```
tail -f /var/lib/mysql/mysql.log
```

You can check the path to your log file with the following command:

```
mysql -u myUsername -p myPassword -e "show variables LIKE 'general_log_file';"
```